# opacity transition is ragged in chrome and chromecast with large images

Tags: css, google-chrome, transition, opacity, chromecast

I'm having a problem with opacity transitions with large images in the Chrome browser and in Chromecast.

They work, but they are "ragged". By that I mean I am getting horizontal noise lines in the image during the transition.

I see this work, e.g., on the Chromecast home screen so it can be done cleanly. I'm doing it in what I thought was the simple, obvious way, but apparently there's a trick to it that I'm not seeing.

Here is the complete HTML for a simple page that demonstrates the problem:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
      <head>
           <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
           <style>
                .opaque {
                    opacity: 1.0;
                    transition: opacity 1s linear;
                }

                .transparent {
                    opacity: 0.0;
                    transition: opacity 1s linear;
                }
           </style>
           <title>Opacity transition test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
           <script>
               function fadeIn() {
                   console.log("::fadeIn()");
                   image = document.getElementById("image");
                   console.log("image is: " + image);
                   image.className = "opaque";
               };
               function fadeOut() {
                   console.log("::fadeOut()");
                   image = document.getElementById("image");
                   console.log("image is: " + image);
                   image.className = "transparent";
               };
           </script>
           <button onclick="fadeIn()">Fade In</button>
           &nbsp;
           <button onclick="fadeOut()">Fade Out</button>
           <br />
           <br />
           <img id="image" class="opaque" src="image.jpg" />
      </body>
 </html>
```

In the third line from the end, replace "image.jpg" with the URL for a reasonably large image (720 x 1280). Or put a reasonably large image named "image.jpg" in the same directory as the HTML when you try running it.

I've tried many variations, but they all show the noise lines when run in the Chrome browser, or when this technique is used in the Chromecast custom receiver I am developing.

If you try this in a browser, be sure to use Chrome to see it, because it doesn't happen in any other browser that I've tried! :-(

Any help anyone can offer on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Jim Renkel

Comment: I have placed this into a [jsfiddle - click here](http://jsfiddle.net/qWTK5/). Please upload the image you are using and link it in this fiddle then click "update" on the jsfiddle page and copy paste the fiddle link into your question.

Comment: misterSamMan: I believe I have done what you requested. Here is the link to the revised fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jim_renkel/qWTK5/1/ When I run it in Firefox, it looks great; Chrome, not so much. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Could you host the image on [http://www.imgur.com/](http://www.imgur.com) and add to the fiddle as that image is protected. [In this fiddle - click here](http://jsfiddle.net/qWTK5/3/) I have a `jpg` and `png` and they seem to have no issues in the latest version of Chrome... Does that [fiddle have problems for you?](http://jsfiddle.net/qWTK5/3/)

Comment: Sorry about the problem with Gdrive. I have the image marked for public access, but I must be doing something wrong. I uploaded the image to http://i.imgur.com/97Ml3gy.jpg (I hope I got this one right!) :-) , and modified the fiddle to use it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jim_renkel/qWTK5/4/ . I also modified the fiddle to display the image at full size: as I said, I'm only having problems with large images. Again, the fiddle displays nicely with Firefox, but is ragged with Chrome. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Ok have the image working :) I really hate to say this, but the transition is smooth as butter for me. Latest Chrome. I have now tried this on both Mac OS X and Windows 7... No issues!

Comment: I have just tried this on my Nexus 4, latest Chrome app. No issues with Android, Mac, or Windows versions of Chrome!

Comment: Hmmm! Must be my old, slow PC running Windows XP, although I do have the latest and greatest version of the Chrome browser. Maybe, this is good, since it accurately reproduces what happens on a Chromecast. :-) Thank for your effort on this.

Comment: No problem. Yes, I would imagine it's caused by slow graphics performance. That would  definitely explain why the chrome cast has the same issue. A work around could be something like a white div overlay that fades to reveal the image and regains opacity to hide. If the overlay is a hex value of `#FFF` and the transition is not on a large image then performance should be fine. I would try it, but I am on my phone!

Comment: misterManSam: we think alike! I am going to try fading a solid "block" in and out over the image (black in my case since the Chromecast background is black). I'll let you know how that works; might be a few days. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @misterManSam I keep forgetting to point out that even on my old, slow winds XP PC, it's only a problem with the chrome browser. Firefox shows nice smooth transitions. Think I'd have any luck asking google to use mozilla on the chromecast? :-)

Answer (score 3):

For a slideshow app, I am doing something along those lines (on chromecast). First, I am using `-webkit-transition` rather than just transition so my css has the following

`-webkit-transition: opacity 4s ease-in;`

You need to play with the time to see what makes sense for you. The other thing that I am doing in my slideshow app is that I have two `<img/>` tags, one which is visible and one which is hidden; I update the hidden one and when that is done, I transition the one in front to 100 transparent, using the transition I showed, and the one hidden to visible and keep going like that so that the transition and loading of image do not interfere. That provides a relatively nice transition.

The current chromecast device lacks certain optimizations; a lot of CSS transitions are done in software. In addition, double-buffering is currently missing; a lot of these are on to-do list and we'll get to them to make this little tiny device even better.

Comment: Ali: thank you for the comments. In my Chromecast app's receiver I am doing as you are: several <img>'s on top of each other that get faded in and out as necessary. All that works, it just doesn't look very good because of the raggedness in the images during the transitions. I've played with the available parameters, and even tried -webkit-transition, but can't get rid of the raggedness. 

I don't see any raggedness on the Chromecast "home page" as it fades images in and out. How are those transitions being done to avoid the raggedness?

Comment: It uses the same technique, no magic is involved. In my application, the transition is relatively smooth (play with the transition length to see if that makes any difference for you or not). You said you have multiple images, maybe you need to reduce the number; theses are things that you have to play with but otherwise, with the current firmware, there is not much options. If your device is whitelisted, you should be able to connect to it and inspect the home application.

Comment: Thanks Ali. I'll try reverse engineering the home app. Since you suggested it, I assume I won't be violating any terms and conditions, or anything. :-)

Comment: @AliNaddaf Is double-buffering one on the to-do list? Simple css, javascript, or canvas animations currently present a lot of tearing that double-buffering should fix.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely o the TO-DO list

Comment: @AliNaddaf Oh, sure. I finally get around to reverse engineering the home app, and, guess what? They took the transitions out of it! :-) It now just displays the same single image forever. Sigh! :-( Any word if transitions will be coming back to the home app? Or how can I get access to an old version that does transitions? Or is there any other thing that does opacity transitions "right" that I can look at? Just looking for any way to figure out how to do it right in my app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AliNaddaf Cancel that. There's no transitions only after the stick is rebooted. After ya run an app and return to the homescreen, then transitions are used. Reverse engineering continues! :-)